# How to plot date and time in the y axis together

Tags: python, pandas, time-series

So I have a data frame including 3 columns: 'Data', 'Date', 'Time'.
I want to plot 'Data' on the x-axis and 'Date' and 'Time' together on the y-axis, since I have 24 values of time per every date value (1 value per hour). However, when I try to plot 'Time' on the x-axis, I get :

```
x = DF['Time']
y=DF['Data']
plt.plot(x,y)
plt.xlabel('Data')
plt.ylabel('NM data counts/hour')
```

TypeError: float() argument must be a string or a number, not 'datetime.time'

On the other hand, when I try plotting 'Date' on the x-axis I do not have a single problem, you can see the plot on the link below.

```
x = DF['Date']
y=DF['Data']
plt.plot(x,y)
plt.xlabel('Data')
plt.ylabel('NM data counts/hour')
```

[You can see the plot here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9X9uF.png)

[The data frame looks like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/e4Qij.png)

The problem is that I have a lot of values per day, that is why I want to plot the 'Date' and 'Time' values together, to plot every Data point with its corresponding Time value. I hope that I am clear enough ):

By the way, the data types are this:

```
DF=NM_data.loc[First_GMS_2011]
DF.dtypes
Date    datetime64[ns]
Time            object
Data             int64
dtype: object
```

And the data frame looks like this:

```
           Date      Time    Data
0    2011-01-01  00:00:00  825361
1    2011-01-01  01:00:00  826873
2    2011-01-01  02:00:00  824004
3    2011-01-01  03:00:00  826001
4    2011-01-01  04:00:00  823890
...         ...       ...     ...
8721 2011-12-31  19:00:00  823309
8722 2011-12-31  20:00:00  821926
8723 2011-12-31  21:00:00  823056
8724 2011-12-31  22:00:00  823263
8725 2011-12-31  23:00:00  823552
```

Best regards!

Comment: use the datetime type for your Date (see. [pd.to_datetime](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.to_datetime.html)) and make sure you data is sorted by Date. Please provide the dataset as text, not images.

Comment: I think it is sorted by date! I edited and provided the dataset as text, sorry :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will want to concat the `Date` and `Time` columns together and convert to a `pd.datetime`. In this answer I also suggest using the `.plot()` method as it's much easier especially when working with time series data like this.

**Firstly, concatenating:**

You can only concat string columns so, since the `Time` column is a datetime.time data type, you will need to convert this to a string using `DF['Time'].astype(str)` before you concatenate. It looks like from your chart that your `Date` column is a string, and not yet a pd.datetime, this makes it easier (if I'm wrong here, add `.astype(str)` to the `DF['Date']` reference below. To add a new column with these concatenated use:

```py
(
    DF
    .assign(datetime = pd.to_datetime(DF['Date'] + ' ' + df['Time'].astype(str)))
)
```

**Secondly, plotting**

With pandas you can use the `.plot()` method. This means you don't have to import `matplotlib` unless necessary. `.plot()` will (by default) plot your dataframe where the index will become your x-axis (we will use `.set_index('datetime')`) and the y axis will be your columns (select one column with `['Data']`).

So in full you can create a new column `datetime` and plot using:

```py
(
    DF
    .assign(datetime = pd.to_datetime(DF['Date'] + ' ' + DF['Time'].astype(str)))
    .set_index('datetime')
    ['Data']
    .plot()
)
```

The reason you see the error is because when you use `plt.plot(x, y)` your x cannot be a series with `datetime.time` data type. It would actually work using the `.plot()` method if you change to `.set_index('Time')` although that never seemed to be your desired output anyway.